# Else without If error after a bunch of ElseIf statements

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an Else without If error after all my ElseIf statements. I'm trying to end my initial If AColValue = "LV Fuses" with an Else statement but it's giving me this error at the Else.

```
Do While j <> 1
    If AColValue = "LV Fuses" Then               'Fuse info starts with a row labelled "LV Fuses" in Col A
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "HV/MV with Trip-Unit" Then '
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "HV/MV without Trip-Unit" Then '
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "Relays" Then             '
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "MCP" Then                '
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "MOL" Then                '
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "HV Fuses" Then           '
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "Switches" Then           '
        j = 1
        Exit Do
    ElseIf AColValue = "" Then                   '
        NumOfBkrs = NumOfBkrs + 1
        RowNumberPlus1 = RowNumber + 1
        AColValue = Range("A" & RowNumberPlus1)
        If AColValue = "" Then
            RowNumberPlus1 = RowNumberPlus1 + 1
            AColValue = Range("A" & RowNumberPlus1)
            If AColValue = "" Then
                j = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Else
    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
End If
AColValue = Range("A" & RowNumber)
Loop
```

Comment: Your [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) needs corrected... that should help you see the problem.

Comment: Also, consider using `Select Case` to simplify this tremendously.

Comment: @BigBen I'm sorry but I don't see a difference when pasting the code in?

Comment: You have to actually click Indent.

Comment: Edited it into your post... and now you have an answer too that points out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your second to last `End If` closes the main `If`.
Then, the following `Else` has no `If`.